# How do you equally divide an inclusive, continuous range?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have an inclusive range from 0 to 100. If I wanted to split this range into five equal-probability segments, how would I do this?

I'm getting stuck when thinking about the endpoints of each segment. For example, I would expect the ranges to look something like this, since each segment is inclusive of one endpoint and exclusive of the other:

$0 \leq x < 20$

$20 \leq x < 40$

$40 \leq x < 60$

$60 \leq x < 80$

$80 \leq x < 100$

However, how do I deal with 100, since 100 is a valid number in this range?

Comment: The probability of getting any of the endpoints is $0$. You can think of it as the ratio of the number of favorable outcomes, which is $1$, to the number of possible outcomes, which is infinity, since you're dealing with a continuous range.

Comment: So it doesn't really matter if you use $<$ or $\leq$

Comment: More rigourously, this is a continuous probability density function. This is a pretty decent resource on the topic:https://opentextbc.ca/introbusinessstatopenstax/chapter/properties-of-continuous-probability-density-functions/

Comment: You do not really have a difficulty if this is uniform over the real number in $[0,100]$ and you can just stick $100$ in the last subset as it has probability $0$.  This approach does not work if you have a uniform distribution over the integers in that interval, as you have $101$ such integers, which is not divisible by $5$